# Lowest Power for Euler Totient Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

If I use the Euler Totient to find the solution of $9^x\equiv1 \pmod{10}$, It gives $x=4$. However $x=2$ also works. Is there a function that gets the smallest $x$ that is a solution? In other terms, is there a function that directly gives the order?

Comment: The smallest such $x$ is called the order (in this case the order of $9$ modulo $10$).

Comment: The order must be a divisor of the exponent you get from Euler's theorem.

Comment: Yes, but is there a function?

Comment: This is probably not exactly what you want, but here is a Wikipedia article related to this: [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). (I wasn't sure whether to add the tag (carmichael-function) or not - feel free to remove it if you think id does not really fit the question.)